# Sort an element in a document in tidytext

Tags: r, ggplot2, rstudio, tidytext

As you can see the legend on the right hand side, I need to reorder it as 1,2,3,...64, not 1,10,11...,8. My term-document matrix is as follows.
   Please give me some ideas how to rearrange the code.

```
    A tibble: 4,530 x 5
   document       term count     n total
  <chr>      <chr> <dbl> <int> <dbl>
1        1      activ     1     1   109
2        10 agencydebt     1     1   109
3        10     assess     1     1   109
4        11      avail     1     1   109
5        11     balanc     2     1   109
```

[The image of my histogram is here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KjOXN.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this line before plotting:

```
df$document = factor(df$document, levels=sort(as.numeric(df$document)))
```

where df is the name of your dataframe.

Comment: Thank you very much Florian!

Comment: Great, glad I could help.